# ANTLR Rule Not Matching

Tags: antlr

This should be a simple question. Given this parser rule:

```
ifStatement
 : expr3b=IF logical (~(THEN)) expression* (ELSE expression *)? ENDIF // missing THEN
 ;
```

Why does this not match this String?

```
"IF CODE=\"10\" DUE_DATE < YESTERDAY ENDIF"
```

(`IF`, `THEN`, `ELSE`, and `ENDIF` are tokens defined to exactly what you'd assume they are. `logical` and `expression` are other rules).

Comment: Without seeing the productions for logical and expression, my guess is that the `CODE = "10"` is a mal-formed expression, perhaps in the lexical handling of `"10"`. But you've given too little information to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the following line is verbatum from your grammar.

```
ifStatement : expr3b=IF logical (~(THEN)) expression* (ELSE expression *)? ENDIF;
```

If that's the case, then you'll want to change it to this:

```
ifStatement : expr3b=IF logical expression* (ELSE expression *)? ENDIF;
```

As it is, `(~(THEN))` says "match any one token, as long as it isn't `THEN`." The first token after `logical` finishes is `ID` (or similar) for `DUE_DATE`. `ifStatement` consumes it to fulfill `(~(THEN))`. This leaves `< YESTERDAY` to fulfill `expression`, which fails.

The following input would be accepted by the `ifStatement` in your question because `ENDIF` fulfills `(~(THEN))`:

```
IF CODE=\"10\" ENDIF DUE_DATE < YESTERDAY ENDIF
```

This would work as expected because the first `ENDIF` is consumed *only* to match `(~(THEN))`.